# SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED in REPETABLE READ transactions

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, isolation-level, locks

I have the following statement in my  PostgreSQL 10.5 database, which I execute in a `repeatable read` transaction:

```
delete from task
  where task.task_id = (
    select task.task_id
    from task
    order by task.created_at asc
    limit 1
    for update skip locked
  )
  returning
    task.task_id,
    task.created_at
```

Unfortunately, when I run it, I sometimes get:

```
[67] ERROR:  could not serialize access due to concurrent update
[67] STATEMENT:  delete from task
  where task.task_id = (
    select task.task_id
    from task
    order by task.created_at asc
    limit $1
    for update skip locked
  )
  returning
    task.task_id,
    task.created_at
```

which means the transaction rolled back because some other transaction modified the record in the meantime. (I think?)

I don't quite understand this. How could a different transaction modify a record that was selected with `for update skip locked`, and deleted?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[This quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-REPEATABLE-READ) discusses your case *exactly*:

> `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, and `SELECT FOR SHARE` commands
>   behave the same as `SELECT` in terms of searching for target rows: they
>   will only find target rows that were committed as of the transaction
>   start time. However, such a target row might have already been updated
>   (or deleted or locked) by another concurrent transaction by the time
>   it is found. In this case, the repeatable read transaction will wait
>   for the first updating transaction to commit or roll back (if it is
>   still in progress). If the first updater rolls back, then its effects
>   are negated and the repeatable read transaction can proceed with
>   updating the originally found row. But if the first updater commits
>   (and actually updated or deleted the row, not just locked it) then the
>   repeatable read transaction will be rolled back with the message
>
> ```
> ERROR:  could not serialize access due to concurrent update
> ```

Meaning, your transaction was unable to lock the row to begin with - due to concurrent write access that got there first. `SKIP LOCKED` cannot save you from this completely as there may not be a lock to skip any more and we still run into a serialization failure if the row has already been changed (and the change committed - hence the lock released) since transaction start.

The same statement should work just fine with default `READ COMMITTED` transaction isolation. Related:

- [Postgres UPDATE … LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69497/3684)

Comment: Thanks for you reply! I see, so before the lock can be taken, but after the transaction starts, a different client manged to delete the row. The reason why I wanted the `REPEATABLE READ` transaction isolation was because in the same transaction I insert a row into a second table. Would it be still safe to do so with `READ COMMITED`?

Comment: @Ynv: Yes, a different transaction that deleted or updated and already committed. Still safe with `READ COMMITTED`? Probably yes, but that all depends on requirements. Safe against what? I suggest you start a ***new question*** with defining details. (If *this* question is answered properly, consider accepting it.)